# Class 'Elibyy\TCPDF\Facades\TCPdf' not found in laravel after uploading to the shared hosting but works fine in localhost host

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, tcpdf, shared-hosting

I use laravel with TCPdf to print pdf in the browser, it works fine in the localhost but when I upload it to shared hosting an error throws Class 'Elibyy\TCPDF\Facades\TCPdf' not found. I went through google to find the solution but still unable to find, so plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
composer update
```

command on server.